# Getting path to file in published webcomponent

Tags: javascript, typescript, path

I have a webcomponent where I need to add a `link` tag to the head and set the `href` equal to a folder inside that node module.

Right now I'm in the building phase of this component where my structure look like this:

[image]

So I need to add the `fontawsome.css` script to the head of my page. I've created the following script:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (!this.isFontAwesomeLoaded()) {
      this.iclass = '';
      const fontEl = document.createElement('link');
      fontEl.rel = 'stylesheet';    
      fontEl.href = "./fontawesome/css/all.css";
      document.head.appendChild(fontEl);    
    }
  }
```

Now there is a problem with this the path `./fontawesome/css/all.css` won't work when it hits the `head` tag because the `index.html` file that attempts to load it doesn't have the folder in its project. instead when it hits product it needs to find the absolute path to my module and then to the `fontawesome` folder.

My question is how can I get that path?

Comment: Are you using pure javascript? Or are you using use some kind of framework like jquery, node.js...?

Comment: @tschomacker i am using  typescript if that matters  :)

Comment: Are you using bare TypeScript (no framework?). Also what are you using as a build process?

Comment: just move `fontawesome` folder to your `assets` or `public` folder or whatever folder you are serving. Then in your script use a relative path from `index.html` to the file you want to load.

Comment: @YuriyKravets this would work however i am creating a web component that should be able to be used on all pages without coupling

Comment: Had the same issue some months ago. I ended up adding pure css icons https://saeedalipoor.github.io/icono/ for my custom web component https://github.com/petergd/pd-indicator. In your case i don't know if the `JS` implementation of FontAwesome if could server better your purpose. See https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/setup/configuration and https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

Comment: Have you tried something like e.g. this `fontEl.href = "../../..//fontawesome/css/all.css` depending on the location of `index.html` from `src` directory?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things that should be avoided:

1. External dependencies from within web-component is a bad idea, especially something big like `fontawesome`. You said that you try to avoid coupling, but actually you introduce it with such dependency.
2. Web-components rarely should be used without shadow-dom (IMHO), by accepting fontawesome you basically ignore that functionality of web-components.

There are a couple of ways you could handle such scenario:

1. extract what you need from fontawesome's `all.css` into your web-component.
2. state in your component's docs that it depends on fontawesome and that the client should provide it on their side
3. use CDN (really bad decision, avoid this):

```
constructor() {
    super();
    if (!this.isFontAwesomeLoaded()) {
      this.iclass = '';
      const fontEl = document.createElement('link');
      fontEl.rel = 'stylesheet';    
      fontEl.href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
      document.head.appendChild(fontEl);    
    }
}
```